# Thread safety in Java hashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap

Is the following code thread safe?

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Double>> hMap = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Double>>();
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
// the next line is new
ArrayList<Future<Double>> results = new ArrayList<Future<Double>>();
for (Integer i = 0; i < iBound; i++) {
    hMap.put(i, new HashMap<Integer, Double>());
    for (Integer j = 0; j < jBound; j++) {
        SomeCallable task = new SomeCallable(i, j);
        Future<Double> result = executor.submit(task);
        results.add(result);  // hMap.get(i).put(j, result.get());
    }
}
executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// the next lines are new
int index = 0;
for (Integer i = 0; i < iBound; i++) {
    hMap.put(i, new HashMap<Integer, Double>());
    for (int j = 0; j < jBound; j++) {
        hMap.get(i).put(j, results.get(index).get());
        index++;
    }
}
```

I would say yes, since different threads work with different keys in the hash maps. I have tested this and compared `hMap` that is obtained in the multi-thread scenario to the `hMap` that is obtained in the following way:

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Double>> hMap = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Double>>();
for (Integer i = 0; i < iBound; i++) {
    hMap.put(i, new HashMap<Integer, Double>());
    for (Integer j = 0; j < jBound; j++) {
        SomeCallable task = new SomeCallable(i, j);
        hMap.get(i).put(j, task.call());
    }
}
```

I varied the number of threads from 2 to 20 and was changing the time complexity of`SomeCallable.call`. The bounds `iBound` and `jBound` were set to `500`.

There were no differences between `hMap`s, but I want to be sure.

Comment: Try using a ConcurrentHashMap instead

Comment: Your executor will only process one task at a time, since you're calling `result.get()` which will block until the result is available.

Answer (score 4):

As long as `SomeCallable` does not internally access the `hMap` instance variable (and is inherently thread safe itself), then this code is safe. We can safely assume that because all manipulations done to `hMap` come from the same thread (each and every put / get come from the thread that performs the loop).

On the other hand, there is no real point in executing all this in a threaded manner if after submitting each task, one immediately waits for this task's completion. You might as well use your second code sample, because in practice, your first only ever uses one thread at a time.

And maybe if you actually start using threading in a more "usefull" way, then you HashMap usage may become unsafe.

Comment: Ok, it seems that I do not understand how `ExecutorService`  should be used. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want me to elaborate a bit on why your threading is not really useful as is in your first code sample, and what could be done about it ? You may also ask a new question altogether, that would keep this one focused, which is good generally speaking

Comment: I have edited the code, so that it actually makes sense to parallelize it. The question is the same. (Turns out I did not fully understand how the pool should be used ...)

Comment: Actually ... Threads are not accessing the hash map, hence the question is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a ConcurrentHashMap instead.  All protections are in place by default.

Comment: Ok, but is this necessary?

Comment: if multiple threads are going to be accessing it, then yes it is.

Comment: In your simple example above you might not run into any issues, although I agree with @GPI that you're using Executors incorrectly.  If, for some reason, you were calling this code from multiple Threads and hMap was shared, then you would def. need to use ConcurrentHashMap.